# Get Sudo Permissions in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions

I am writing an installer script in Python 3. Eventually, there's a prompt to either install the program locally or for all users. It will not work if the user selects all users, because the program needs sudo permissions to move the file to `/usr/share/applications`.

How do I get the permissions to move the file to that location, but keep the user logged into their own user (not root)?

Python 3.10.6
Linux

I have tried using `sudo` but there's a point in the program where it finds the user's home directory, and if they run it with `sudo`, it thinks that `/root` is their home directory, which messes everything up.

Comment: you could try to build a program by compiling files using `Cython` or another module that install software like [`PyInstaller`](https://pyinstaller.org); PD, I do not know if this allow user sudo permissions to move file between paths but you probably need to use another *third-party* together to be able to perform any certain operation between folder and files, i hope to help you thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do something like this with the os module (note I do not use linux so the shell command may be incorrect!)

```
import os
os.system('sudo mv yourfile /usr/share/applications')
```